# How to use a switch statement on something like UITraitEnvironmentLayoutDirection?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, swift4, swift4.2, uitraitcollection

I want to find the value of `UITraitEnvironmentLayoutDirection`. It has the possible values of `.leftToRight`, `.rightToLeft` and `.unspecified`.

How do I use a `switch` (or some other statement) to detect which of these is the correct value?

I have tried the following:

```
switch UITraitEnvironmentLayoutDirection {
        case .leftToRight:
            print("left to right")
        case .rightToLeft:
            print("right to left")
        default:
            print("unknown")
    }
```

and it isn't valid syntax. So what is? How do I get the value?

Comment: You should be switching an instance of that enum.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Can you please show me how to do that? I looked at enum and I still had no success.

Comment: Where are you using this piece of code? Show the rest of your code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I wish to get the screen's orientation. Instead of the print statements I will set it to something like "left" or "right". I don't see how any other code is necessary, please can you give me the enum statement to get the UITraitEnvironmentLayoutDirection?